# Return the maximum of (two) element-wise added vectors

Tags: c++, stdvector

I wrote a function that first adds two vectors (`v1` and `b1` are added to `vsum`) and than returns the maximum of `vsum`. Here is what I tried to run, it doesn't work for some reason:

```
double MaximumOfSummedVectors(std::vector<double> &v1,std::vector<double> &v2) {
    std::vector<double> vsum;
    std::transform(v1.begin(),v1.end(),v2.begin(),vsum.begin(),std::plus<double>());
    return *std::max_element(std::begin(vsum),std::end(vsum));
}
```

I've tested both the functionality of `std::transform`, `std::max_element` and `std::plus<double>` in my main environment. Everything worked as expected. What am I overlooking?

Comment: use `std::valarray` then you can do `(v1+b1+vsum).max();`

Comment: FWIW, Boost has a zip iterator, so you could have a one line `max_element` call, or a couple lines to create begin and end variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overlooking two things: the first is undefined behavior!

```
std::vector<double> vsum;
```

`vsum` has size zero at this point. But `transform` will just write into the iterator you pass in

> Effects: Assigns through every iterator i in the range `[result,result + (last1 - first1))` a new corresponding value equal to ...

But that range isn't initialized - so you're going to be writing to uninitialized memory! You need to do either:

```
vsum.resize(v1.size());
```

or pass an inserter:

```
std::transform(v1.begin(),v1.end(),v2.begin(),
     std::back_inserter(vsum),
     std::plus<double>());
```

The second thing is that you're constructing this whole new vector for little reason:

```
double MaximumOfSummedVectors(std::vector<double> &v1,std::vector<double> &v2) 
{
     auto i1 = v1.begin(), i2 = v2.begin();
     double m = *i1++ + *i2++;
     for (; i1 != v1.end(); ++i1, ++i2) {
         m = std::max(m, *i1 + *i2);
     }
     return m;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer!

Answer (score 0):

You pass `vsum.begin()` as the output argument. This assumes that there's enough space in the vector to write the output sequence, when in fact the vector is empty; so the output is written off the end of the vector into undefined territory.

Instead, you want to insert the output values into the vector, using an insertion interator `std::back_inserter(vsum)`.